# Alexa timeout wait time for the response

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

Here is the scenario

1) Alexa sends a request to an API

2) API handles the request and functionality and sends back a response

**Please find my questions below**

> How long can the API take to respond back to Alexa or in other words
>   how long will Alexa (echo) device wait for the response until it times
>   out ?
>
> Also it is configurable?
>
> Any solution to make sure the API returns back the response before a
>   timeout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Alexa timeout is 10 seconds and you cannot change this, please follow this [thread](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/9176/what-is-the-timeout-of-the-request-sent-by-alexa.html)